# laravel php artisan serve not serving the current directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Whenever I try to run

```
php artisan serve
```

on my newly created laravel project directory, it always serve the other project from another directory.

I am using homestead virtual box's latest version with vagrant.

If I try to delete/rename the project that is being served, then run php artisan serve on my new project, the browser will show

```
No input file specified.
```

Comment: Are you serving another application at the same time? Try changing the port: `php artisan serve --port=8080`. `8000` is the default one.

Comment: Why even doin a `php artisan serve`, if you use homestead you automatically have an active webserver with your linked projects